# IAM access to EC2 REST API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm new to `AWS`. My client uses `AWS` to host his `EC2` instances. Right now, we are trying to get me API access. Obviously, I need my authentication details to do this.

He set me up an IAM identity under his account, so I can login to the `AWS` web console and configure EC2 instances. I cannot, however, for the life of me, figure out where my API access keys are displayed. I don't have permissions to view 'My Account', which is where I imagine they'd be displayed.

So, what I'm asking, is how can he grant me API access through his account? How can I access the AWS API using my IAM identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Michael - sqlbot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882796/45773) is correct (+1), but not entirely complete given the comparatively recent but highly useful addition of [Variables in AWS Access Control Policies](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/04/variables-in-aws-access-control-policies.html):

> Today we’re extending the AWS access policy language to include
>   support for variables. [Policy variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html) make it easier to create
>   and manage general policies that include individualized access
>   control.

This enables implementation of an 'IAM Credentials Self Management' group policy, which would usually be assigned to the most basic IAM group like the common 'Users'.

- Please note that the following solution still needs to be implemented by the AWS account owner (or an IAM user with permissions to manage IAM itself), but this needs to be done once only to enable credentials self management by other users going forward.

### Official Solution

A respective example is included in the introductory blog post (and <strike>meanwhile</strike> has been available at [Allow a user to manage his or her own security credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iampolicy-example-usermanagecred) in the IAM documentation too - **Update**: this example vanished again, presumably due to being applicable via custom solutions using the API only and thus confusing):

> Variable substitution also simplifies **allowing users to manage their
>   own credentials**. If you have many users, you may find it impractical
>   to create individual policies that allow users to create and rotate
>   their own credentials. With variable substitution, **this becomes
>   trivial to implement as a group policy**. The following policy permits
>   any IAM user to perform any of the key and certificate related actions
>   on their own credentials. *[emphasis mine]*

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":["iam:*AccessKey*","iam:*SigningCertificate*"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/${aws:username}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The resource scope `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/${aws:username}` ensures that every user is effectively only granted access to his own credentials.

Please note that this solution still has usability flaws depending on how AWS resources are accessed by your users, i.e. via API, CLI, or the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) (the latter requires additional permissions for example).

Also, the various `*` characters are a wildcard, so `iam:*AccessKey*` addresses all IAM actions containing `AccessKey` (see [IAM Policy Elements Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html) for details).

### Extended Variation

**Disclaimer:** The correct configuration of IAM policies affecting IAM access in particular is obviously delicate, so please make your own judgement concerning the security impact of the following solution!

Here's a more explicit and slightly extended variation, which includes [AWS Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)](http://aws.amazon.com/mfa/) device self management and a few usability enhancements to ease using the AWS Management Console:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
        "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:GetLoginProfile",
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:ListGroupsForUser",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
        "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
        "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
        "iam:UploadSigningCertificate"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:mfa/${aws:username}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks... you're right.  I wasn't aware of this and my answer is incomplete without it. +1.

Comment: I can't get the Extended Variation to allow users self service through AWS Console without adding iam:ListUsers (and iam:ListVirtualMFADevices for MFA device self-service) on all users in the account. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

"You" can't, but:

In IAM, under Users, after he selects your user, he needs to click Security Credentials > Manage Access Keys, and then choose "Create Access Key" to create an API Key and its associated Secret, associated with your IAM user.  On the next screen, there's a message:

> Your access key has been created successfully.
>
> This is the last time these User security credentials will be available for download.
>
> You can manage and recreate these credentials any time.

Where "manage" means "deactivate or delete," and "recreate" means "start over with a new one."  The IAM admin can subsequently see the keys, but not the associated secrets.

From that screen, and only from that screen, and only right then, is where the IAM admin can view the both key and the secret associated with the key or download them to a CSV file.  Subsequently, one with appropriate privileges can see the keys for a user within IAM but you can never view the secret again after this one chance (and it would be pretty preposterous if you could).

So, your client needs to go into IAM, under the user he created for you, and create an API key/secret pair, save the key and secret, and forward that information to you via an appropriately-secure channel... if he created it but didn't save the associated secret, he should delete the key and create a new one associated with your username.

If you don't have your own AWS account, you should sign up for one so you can go into the console with full permissions as yourself and understand the flow... it might make more sense than my description.

Comment: Michael, not sure if you are stalking me or just very quick to answer. I'll hope its the latter! ;P Anyway, thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: @EthanBarron lol, nope, not stalking :) I monitor the site for new questions on my two areas of specialization, MySQL and AWS.  Ask about something else and it's reasonably unlikely that you'll hear from me.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - +1 for the extensive explanation and stressing the need for a secure channel for passing credentials! I've added a [secondary answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19891729/45773) expanding on yours with the recent IAM addition of [Variables in AWS Access Control Policies](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/04/variables-in-aws-access-control-policies.html) to enable self management of credentials for users.